# Network visibility within docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, docker-network

I have built a docker-compose with 3 services: `db`, `nginx`, `selenium`.
App hosted with nginx communicates with database (`nginx` <-> `db`), and selenium tests app (`selenium` -> `app`).

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: <my_private_repo>/nginx
    ...
  db:
    image: <my_private_repo>/db
    # nginx cannot communicate with db after I remove exposing port 3306
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    ...
  selenium:
    image: joyzoursky/python-chromedriver:3.8-selenium
    command: "bash seleniumScript.sh"
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - db
```

I run my tests with `docker-compose run selenium`
Everything works when I expose database port but when I stop exposing port 3306 nginx is unable to communicate with db.

My understanding was that all services within one docker-compose setup are automatically connected and user doesn't need to create any additional networks but I was obviously wrong.

My question is how should I setup exposing ports between services without exposing them to host machine?

Update:
My nginx app has configured database host to service name `db`. Selenium script setup fill database using `db` host and tests nginx app via `https://nginx` url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60823166/why-a-angular-container-needs-a-exposed-port-to-connect/60823265#60823265) here asks something very similar.

The nginx container cannot reach the database container probably, because you're accessing it via **docker host** `localhost`.

Containers that are in the same network can always reach each other without exposing any ports, but using hostnames. See: [the docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). That means, that you can connect to the database container from inside the nginx container using `db:3306`.

Compose by default [creates a default network for the project](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), so unless you want to prevent some containers from being able to communicate with each other, you won't have to create any new networks.

Comment: My goal for this setup is to not expose anything. I want isolated environment for CI tests and after tests are finished I want to get rid of containers. So to sum up, all containers should see each other on any port via hostnames `db`, `nginx`, `selenium`? Your suggestion is I might have some unresolved dependency to docker host machine `localhost`? Or is it so that if I expose port in `db` it is somehow visible via `nginx` localhost?

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify. You understood correctly: I think you have an unresolved dependency to the docker host machine and all containers in the same network can talk to each other, but you should/need to set fixed container names for predictable hostnames.

Comment: Ok, so I need to find this dependency to confirm. My app settings for database connection uses `db`.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to `db` on port 3306?

Comment: Well I found the problem, my nginx app had cached config changes and it was accessing app via docker host hostname (not localhost). Thanks I got some things cleared out thanks to this answer.